# Assuming x is a number smaller than 0xff what happens to x after the assignment LOBYTE(x)=x-1?

Tags: ida, assembly, c

I understand that [LOBYTE](https://github.com/nihilus/hexrays_tools/blob/master/code/defs.h) is an IDA macro for retrieving the lower byte of a variable. My question is what is the difference between the result of `x=x-1` and `LOBYTE(x)=x-1` when `x` is smaller than or equal to `0xff`? I should add that I'm implicitly assuming that `x>0`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Quote From Link     
#define LOBYTE(x)   (*((_BYTE*)&(x)))
```

is that a hypothetical query x is treated as address
so x-1 will be a 32 bit type on a x86 machine so theoretically
you cannot assign a 32 bit type to an 8 bit type
LOBYTE(x) will be a byte and not an address so again
theoretically you cannot assign a byte to a byte

LOBYTE(x) is an **AND** operation that extracts the unsigned byte from a specific address

```
x as address    contents         LOBYTE(x)     (byte *)&x = LOBYTE(x)-1
0x00400000      0xffffffff       0x000000ff    byte[0x004000000] = 0x000000ff -1 =0x000000fe
```

so if you look as a DWORD **0x400000 will now contain 0xfffffffe**

demo using a python script

```
:\>cat LOBYTE.py
import ctypes

def LOBYTE(arg):
    return arg.value & 0x000000ff

x = ctypes.c_ulong(0xffffffff)
print( "x as address" , ctypes.byref(x))
print( "x holds"  , hex(x.value))
print("result of LOBYTE(x)", LOBYTE(x))
x.value = ( (x.value & 0xffffff00 ) | LOBYTE(x)- 1 )
print( "x holds"  , hex(x.value))


:\>python LOBYTE.py
x as address <cparam 'P' (017CA098)>
x holds 0xffffffff
result of LOBYTE(x) 255
x holds 0xfffffffe
```